# Iframed (using iframe-resizer) site using SSL, width not scaling on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm using the excellent iframe-resizer script (https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer), I have this working across the board, except for a specific situation. The site I have in my iframe uses https:// (siteB.com) and the site where my iframe resides (siteA.com) uses http://. This gives me the following error: "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://siteB.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://www.siteA.com')." The calculation of the iframe works everywhere except on the iPhone (Safari), where the width is not calculated correctly (it's wider), could it be this error that's causing the problem? SiteB.com uses iframeResizer.contentWindow.js, so no problem there.

Tried to put a page from the same site (SiteA.com) in the iframe and this works without a problem on the iPhone. So is this an SSL problem or what could it be? Help very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: Have you set the checkOrigin option?

Comment: @DavidBradshaw Yes, checkOrigin is set to false.

Comment: I think the error is a red herring. The script tries to call the iFrame when first run, if it has not finished loading, then you can sometimes get this error. It also then waits for the iFrame on load event and tries again. Which is why it the works for you.

Comment: I'd suggest making a simple test case and the. Raising a ticket on GitHub for the iPhone issue.